# Smarty include with no include file

Tags: include, smarty

I have a basic page: base.tpl which contains the header and footer of every page on my site. Specific pages (Example: home.tpl) extends ({extends file='../templates/base.tpl'}) the basepage. In the base page I have an include for a statusbar, right underneath the header 
({include file=$statusbar}). I include the right statusbar depending if the user is logged in or logged out... But in some occasions, I don't wish to include the statusbar. When the user chose to register, I just want to show the register form, or when a user has tried to loggin and fail I wish to show him a detailed page, with extra info on how to register/retrieve password. 
But if I try to include an empty value ($smarty->assign("statusbar","")) I get an error and nothing on the page renders. I was considering adding a blank .tpl and link to it. But I was wondering if that is a "good" solution. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can define blocks for you template sections. Then on your extending templates leave blank that blocks
ex: base.tpl

```
<head>{block name = "head"}<title>Welcome</title>{/block}</head>
{block name = "status_bar"}{include file = $statusbar}{/block}
{block name = "footer"}Some footer{/block}
```

ex :register.tpl

```
{extends file = 'base.tpl'}
{block name = 'head'}<title>Register</title>{/block}
{block name = 'status_bar'}{/block}
```

If you do not to want change the content of any block just dont type

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to add a conditional to see if $statusbar has any value:

```
{if $statusbar!=''}
   {include file=$statusbar}
{/if}
```